# How to insert comma in the value which is present in Hyperlink column in gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, hyperlink

Here is my markup:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Loss" SortExpression="Loss" 
     HeaderStyle-CssClass="StrongText" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" 
     HeaderStyle-Font-Size="Medium" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="Blue" 
     HeaderStyle-Font-Underline="true" HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Bottom"  
     ItemStyle-Width="3%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" 
     ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Bottom" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="HyperLink8" 
              NavigateUrl='<%#"db_LossofPay.aspx?UserID="+ Eval("User ID")%>' 
              Text='<%# Eval("Loss","{0}")%>' 
              ForeColor="BLUE" Target="_blank"></asp:HyperLink>
         <asp:Label ID="lblLoss" runat="server"></asp:Label>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Could you please help me with this? In BoundField I wrote `DataFormatString="{0:N2}"` which works fine, but I got stuck when using in hyperlink (template field)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with this:

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="HyperLink8"
 NavigateUrl='<%#"db_LossofPay.aspx?UserID="+   Eval("User ID")%>' 
 Text='<%# Eval("Loss","{0:#,##0.00}") %>' ForeColor="BLUE" Target="_blank" />
```

Comment: How can achieve the same thing in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26466942/how-to-use-csv-format-to-display-data-in-a-repeater

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Text='<%# String.Format("{0:N2}", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Loss"))%>'
```